# sort javascript array in object, maintaining key

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a javascript object with two array's as shown,

```
var Object = {'name': [Matt, Tom, Mike...], 'rank': [34,1,17...]};
```

I am trying to sort by rank 1,2,3.. but keep the name associated with the rank.

```
Object.name[0] // tom
Object.rank[0] // tom's rank of 1.
```

Should I reconfigure my object to make sorting easier?

I am currently using the

```
 Object.rank.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
```

to order rank, but the name does not stay with it.

All help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Better to change your object to hold data in a different format and Object is a bad variable name.

Comment: My object is not named object.. I just thought it would be simpler... guess not..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, reconfigure. Say you had this instead:

```
var people = [{name:"Matt", rank:34}, {name:"Tom", rank:1}, {name:"Mike", rank:17}];
```

Then you could sort like this:

```
people.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.rank - b.rank;
}
```

**Edit**

Since you have parallel lists, just zip them together:

```
var people = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.name.length; i++) {
  people.push({name:Object.name[i], rank:Object.rank[i]});
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I knew there had to be a more intuitive way around this.

Comment: so. I have my people object as you show. [{name:val}, {name:val}], But I am struggling to alert(people.name[0]) and also my var, while created with out of the function, and with a async:false POST, can not be used outside code... Any ideas?

Comment: That would actually be `people[0].name`.

Answer (score 2):

**The real world object:**

```
 o = {name: ['Matt', 'Tom', 'Mike'], rank: [34,1,17]};
```

**Make an array for better data structure:**

```
var arr =[]; 
o.name.forEach(function(name, i){
      arr.push({name: name, rank: o.rank[i]})
});
```

**Sort by rank:**

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.rank - b.rank});
```

**Sort by name:**

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.name- b.name});
```

**Revert back to your original data structure:**

```
o = {name:[], rank:[]}
arr.forEach(function(item){
   o.name.push(item.name);
   o.rank.push(item.rank);
});
```

Comment: forEach is nice. Is that a Mozilla extension or is it cross-browser?

Comment: [`ForEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is available in most browsers and can have a fallback in older browsers.

Comment: Thanks Mohsen!  I like your forEach method best for reconfiguring the current object

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, if the i-th object in `names` array is connected to the i-th object in the `rank` array, you should represent it that way. This means, you should use a `Person` (or whatever it is) object with two properties: `name` and `rank`.

```
// person constructor
function Person(name, rank) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rank = rank;
}

// create the object with the array
var myObject = {
    myArray: new Array()
};

// populate the array
myObject.myArray.push(new Person('Matt', 34));
myObject.myArray.push(new Person('Tom', 1));
myObject.myArray.push(new Person('Mike', 17));

// sort the Person objects according to their ranks
myObject.myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.rank - a.rank;    
});
```

Comment: Great! looks solid.  Ill give it a go!

Comment: In this case not sure making a special Person object has any advantage over a generic object. I guess later down the line you might want to do `instanceof` on it?

Comment: @darkporter Well that's hard to tell from one snippet of code, isn't it? Maybe a special Person object will come in handy for further functionality, maybe not at all...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own sort function that for each sorting operation, remembers what index comes where per iteration in the ranks array. The do the same move from source index to destination index in the names array. (edit) One algortihm for this from the top of my head is the bubblesort, look it up.

The other option is to look for some kind of "map" collection implementation.