# Java Multiple Array Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

Hi I currently have 4 arrays all holding different data the issue i have run into is that i want to sort one of the arrays alphabetically which normally i would just do like this

```
class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<String> {
   public int compare(String strA, String strB) {
      return strA.compareToIgnoreCase(strB);
   }
}
IgnoreCaseComparator icc = new IgnoreCaseComparator();
java.util.Collections.sort(ARRAY,icc);
```

Where ARRAY would be the array I want to sort Alphabetically however I need the arrays to sort together.

So for example lets say my arrays look like this

```
Pet Array: [Dog, Cat, Bird]
Owner Array: [Jim, Kyle, Joe]
Friend Array: [Jake, Jim, John]
Cat Array: [false, true, false]
```

And i want to sort based on Pet Array my output should be like this where all of the third values are now the first and the first values are now the third (This is way over simplified my actual arrays contains thousands of inputs)

```
Pet Array: [Bird, Cat, Dog]
Owner Array: [Joe, Kyle, Jim]
Friend Array: [John, Jim, Jake]
Cat Array: [false, true, false]
```

Is there an easy way to do this where i can sort one array and have the others follow. Thank you for any help with this issue.

**===EDIT===**

Other than my solution being slightly different cause i did a little reading the checked answer is perfect i only have a slightly different return line in the compareTo method

```
    class Entity implements Comparable<Entity> {
        String Pet;
        String Owner;
        String Friend;
        int Cat;

        Entity(String Pet, String Owner, String Friend, int Cat) {
          this.Pet = Pet;
          this.Owner = Owner;
          this.Friend = Friend;
          this.Cat = Cat;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entity other) {
            return this.Pet.compareToIgnoreCase(other.Pet);
        }
     }
```

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081242/sort-javascript-array-in-object-maintaining-key/10081290) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare an object:

```
class Entity implements Comparable<Entity> {
    Pet pet;
    Person owner;
    Friend friend;
    boolean cat;

    Entity(Pet pet, Person owner, Friend friend, boolean cat) {
      this.pet = pet;
      this.owner = owner;
      this.friend = friend;
      this.cat = cat;
    }

    public int compareTo(Entity b) {
      return pet.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(b.pet.getName());
    }
 }
```

Then build an array or a list of these objects. And the sort.

```
Entity[] array = new Entity[pets.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pets.length) {
    array[i] = new Entity(pets[i], owners[i], friends[i], cats[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(array);
```

After that you can split it back to arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pets.length) {
    pets[i] = array[i].pet;
    owners[i] = array[i].owner;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please just show me how to add the arrays to the object and then fetch them back i'm not completely understanding

Comment: think i figured it from this thread will try your suggession in a second thanks http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37594-create-an-object-array/

Comment: Please see my edit above it isn't working correctly at the moment

Comment: Yea that was my original thought i should have mentioned i tried that before commenting it still wants to add that method in the difference is the compareTo doesn't have two variables in it, it only has the one see my edit to my question for what eclipse is adding

Comment: Just got it to work did some reading i'll update my post to my final solution and check your answer thanks looks perfect very happy :)

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated never used this before and will definately be using this a lot in the future have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

1. You can create a `class Tuple` that holds for fields: `pet`,
   `owner`, `friend` and `cat` - with the relevant types for each.
2. Make this class implement `Comparable`, which is basically just
   comparing according to the relevant field. [Or, alternatively -
   implement a matching `Comparator` for this class].
3. Create a `Tuple[] combinedArray` [or a `List<Tuple>`], and populate it with your data.
4. Now, you can just sort combinedArray - and you have the data as you
   need.
5. All is left to do - is iterate the sorted array - and spread the
   data back to the original arrays/lists.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make one array containing an object containing the fields Pet, Owner, Friend and Cat and have the comparator sort by the field you want.

```
class PetContainer { // Find a better name
    public String Pet, Owner, Friend;
    public bool Cat;
}
```

And then put them in an array and

```
class IgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator<PetContainer> {
    public int compare(PetContaier PA, PetContainer PB) {
        return PA.Pet.compareToIgnoreCase(PB.Pet);
    }
}
```

This is just a rough sketch. Make a get method instead of accessing them by their field and make some decent names for the fields.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

to do this in java you will need to write your own construct to do this.

You are looking for associative array functionality. To get this type of functionality you can use a hashmap or hashtable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
public class CustomeDataType 
{
    private String owner;
    private String friend;
    private Boolean isCat;
    // etc
}

Map<String, CustomDataType > petArray = new HashMap<String, CustomeDataType>();
```