# Merge Sort - Sorting String Array with Int Array

Tags: java, mergesort

For this project, I'm given an array of strings and an array of ints. int[1] is the ranking for string[1]. I need to sort the int array in order from 1 to n using mergesort, which I've done below. But I also need to switch the positions of the string array when the int array gets moved so they are both sorted, if that makes sense? I can't figure out what's wrong with my coding or even if my idea will actually work, but I keep getting an array index out of bounds error on stringSorted[k] = stringRight[j] and I can't figure out if there's a way to fix this. Essentially, when an int was added to the sortedInt array, I also added that element to the sorted String array. Thank you for any help, and let me know if something doesn't make sense

```
private static int sortAndCount(int intToSort[]){

    int inversionsLeft;
    int inversionsRight;
    int inversionsMerged;

    if(intToSort.length == 1){
        return 0;
    }

    int m = intToSort.length/2;

    int[] intLeft = new int[m];
    stringLeft = new String[m];

    int[] intRight = new int[intToSort.length-m];
    stringRight = new String[intToSort.length-m];


    for (int i=0; i < m; i++){
        intLeft[i] = intToSort[i];
        stringLeft[i] = stringToSort[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < intRight.length; i++){
            intRight[i] = intToSort[m+i];
            stringRight[i] = stringToSort[m+i];
    }

    inversionsLeft = sortAndCount(intLeft);
    inversionsRight = sortAndCount(intRight);

    intSorted = new int[intToSort.length];
    stringSorted = new String[stringToSort.length];

    inversionsMerged = mergeAndCount(intLeft, intRight);

    return(inversionsLeft + inversionsRight + inversionsMerged);

}

private static int mergeAndCount(int[] intLeft, int[] intRight){

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while(i < intLeft.length && j < intRight.length){

        if(intLeft[i] < intRight[j]){
            intSorted[k] = intLeft[i];
            stringSorted[k] = stringLeft[i];
            i++;
        }

        else{
            intSorted[k] = intRight[j];
            stringSorted[k] = stringRight[j];
            count += intLeft.length - i + 1;
            j++;
        }

        k++;

    }

     while (i < intLeft.length)
        {
            intSorted[k] = intLeft[i];
            stringSorted[k] = stringLeft[i];
            k++;
            i++;

        }

     while (j < intRight.length)
        {
            intSorted[k] = intRight[j];
            stringSorted[k] = stringRight[j];
            j++;
            k++;

        }

     return count;

}

}
```

Comment: A good way to debug these sorts of problems is to check your array lengths.  I suspect that somewhere down the line your array is one value shorter than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks.. I've been working on debugging it and just can't find the error. Will continue working on it though. What really confuses me is that the arrays are the same size.. and it works fine with just the int arrays which made me think this just isn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182462/java-multiple-array-sorting

Comment: The first solution to that could work.. But I'd have to create a whole extra class and I don't think that's very efficient. Is the way I'm doing it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] intLeft = new int[m];
stringLeft = new String[m];

int[] intRight = new int[intToSort.length-m];
stringRight = new String[intToSort.length-m];
```

You'll notice here that for the int arrays you are creating new variables, for the string you are replacing the outer.  This is making your `string` arrays smaller with each recursive call whereas your `int` arrays are passed to each method.

By the time you get to calling `mergeAndCount`, `stringLeft` and `stringRight` are very small whereas the appropriately sized `intLeft` and `intRight` are passed as arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix the problem based of this :)